# Redirect git shell command output of stdout into dialog and stderr into var in Cygwin

Tags: bash, git, redirect, dialog, cygwin

I've been trying to make a `dialog --progressbox` or `--prgbox` displaying `stderr` output during the progress of `git status -s` and `git fetch`, while redirecting the `stdout` result into the var 'git_status'.

As for `--prgbox`, dialog obviously doesn't parse `bash` commands, but `sh` only, things get even more difficult, since command substitution and other bash approaches won't work there, or would require nested double quotes, which also will fail.

```
#local dia_cmd="printf -v git_status '%s' "'$(git status -s)'" "
local dia_cmd="git status -s | printf -v git_status '%s' "
dialog --timeout 1 --prgbox "Updating Git status changes..." "${dia_cmd}" 12 120

dialog --timeout 1 --progressbox "Updating Git status changes..." 80 120 < <(gitStatusCmd git_status )
```

I've tried different variations of redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`, of which none worked, e. g.:

```
exec 4>&2-
git_status="$(git status -s | tee /dev/fd/3 | dialog --progressbox "Updating Git status changes..." 30 120 1>&4)" 3>&1

exec 4<&2
_git_status="$(git status -s | tee /dev/fd/3 &2- | dialog --progressbox "Updating Git status changes..." 30 120 1>&4)" 3>&1
```

Trying to apply the suggestions here wouldn't help either:
[tee and assigning to variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/989742/tee-and-assigning-to-variable)

```
{ _git_status="$(git fetch | tee /dev/fd/3 | dialog --progressbox "Fetching Git changes..." 30 120)"; } 3>&1
```

It always ends up in either `stdout` not being stored into the var, or `stderr` and git info messages suppressed, or displayed in tty, instead of the dialog's box.

Is there a way to make this work properly in Cygwin?

Comment: There's a bug of sorts in `git fetch` where the `--progress` indicator output doesn't come out unless output is going to a tty, even with `--progress`. This is not fixable without going into the Git source code. In any case progress output goes to stderr (which is also annoying in a different way, but there's a good reason for that and once the bug with `--progress` is fixed you could probably, er, make progress here).

Comment: Whether, and if so how, you can work around the bug in Cygwin, I don't know. On a Unix/Linux system, you can open a pty and do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your input, is there already a bug filed against Git for that issue?

Comment: No. The problem is that `git fetch` runs several other Git processes and one of them is the one that needs a `--progress` flag, but it doesn't have one. I ran into this when I was automating a multi-fetch sequence in Python and wanted to do progress indicators, but that was back in 2016 or so.